# Bind and validate inputs for model which has IList

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

I need form on which I have inputs that should be bind for list in model... Example

```
public class InviteMembersViewModel
    {
        public InviteMembersViewModel()
        {
            Members = new List<InviteMemberViewModel>();
        }
        public IList<InviteMemberViewModel> Members { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }
```

I try like this

```
$addNewItem.on('click', function () {
            var templateString = '<div id="item-template'+index+'">'
                + '<div class="card h-100 d-flex flex-column mx-2 px-2 py-3 mt-3 js-item-container">'
                + '<div class="d-flex">'
                + '<div class="flex-grow-1 mb-3 row">'
                + '<div class="text-nowrap text-100 text-dark-l2 col-md-6">'
                + '<label class="label">@Resources.EmailAddress</label>'
                + '<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-email="Please enter email in name@domain form." data-val-length="Maximum number of characters is 256." data-val-length-max="256" data-val-length-min="0" data-val-regex="Please enter email in name@domain form." data-val-regex-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+' + '@Resources.AtSign' + '[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$" data-val-required="Email should not be empty." id="Members_' + index + '_Email" name="Members_' + index +'_Email" type="text" value="">'
                + '<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Members_' + index + '_Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>'
                + '</div>'
                + '<div class="text-nowrap text-100 text-dark-l2 col-md-6">'
                + '<label class="label">@Resources.NameOptional</label>'
                + '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Members_' + index + '_Name" name="Members_' + index + '_Name" value />'
                + '</div>'
                + '</div>'
                + '</div>'
                + '<div class="position-tr m-1 dropdown dd-backdrop dd-backdrop-none-md">'
                + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-brc-tp btn-bgc-tp btn-text-pale btn-light-red js-remove-item">'
                + '<i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i>'
                + '</button>'
                + '</div>'
                + '</div>'
                + '</div>';
            $container.append($(templateString));
            index++;
        });
```

Binding is working but JQuery validation of form is always true even if on server ModelState is false.

To make matters worse, If I use @Html.TextBoxFor and bind just one element from List, validation work correctly but if I manually add input and bind name for model property, that doesn't work.

Please, help me. What I have to do?

Comment: Could you please share more code to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Rena Thank you. I solved this issue. I appended input elements dynamically (onclick event) and jQuery validate works on way that it have to remove validator from form and parse form again. After dynamically appending I use this code and it's solve all my problems: 

'var form = $('#inviteForm').removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");  

$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);'